# Convert a N-ary tree from bottom up without recursion

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Considering a N-ary tree with this node structure:

```
class NodeTypeA {
  String payload;
  List<NodeTypeA> children;

}
```

And we want to convert the tree to `NodeTypeB` tree, but the internal structure of `NodeTypeB` is invisible, and we can only construct the new tree using two method:

```
//This method can only convert leaf NodeTypeA (no children)
public NodeTypeB convertLeaf(NodeTypeA nodeTypeA);

//This method can convert a non-leaf NodeTypeA as long as its children are converted
public NodeTypeB convertParent(NodeTypeA parentNodeTypeA, List<NodeTypeB> nodeTypeBs);
```

The recursive solution is trivial, how can we do it in non-recursive way?

Recursive solution

```
public NodeTypeB convert(NodeTypeA root) {
  if(root == null) return null;
  
  if(root.children == null || root.children.size() == 0) {
  return convertLeaf(root);
  }  
 
  List<NodeTypeB> nodeBs = new ArrayList<>();
  for(NodeTypeA child：root.children) {
      nodeBs.add(convert(child));
  }
  return convertParent(root, nodeBs);

}
```

Comment: Can you share the recursive solution?

Comment: added recursive solution

Comment: Is your question java-specific? There's a Python solution here: [Postorder traversal of an n ary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606017/postorder-traversal-of-an-n-ary-tree)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stack for this. A stacked element should have a reference to a `NodeTypeA` instance, and to a list of `NodeTypeB` instances. As long as the size of that list is smaller than the number of children of the `NodeTypeA` node, the stack should be extended with the next child of `NodeTypeA` that has not yet been mapped. When a node can be mapped, it is appended to the list of `NodeTypeB` instances at the top of the stack, and the process continues with the next child (if any).

When the number of children is equal, then all has been done for the stacked `NodeTypeA` instance, and all is available to create an internal `NodeTypeB` node. This item can then be popped from the stack, and the created node can be appended to the list that is now on the top of the stack.

This continues until the stack is empty.

As implementation, you could first define this simple class:

```java
public class NodeHybrid {
    NodeTypeA parentA;
    List<NodeTypeB> childrenB = new ArrayList<>();

    NodeHybrid(NodeTypeA parent) {
        parentA = parent;
    }
}
```

And then the `convert` function could look like this:

```java
public NodeTypeB convert(NodeTypeA root) {
    if (root == null) return null;
    Stack<NodeHybrid> stack = new Stack<NodeHybrid>();
    stack.push(new NodeHybrid(root));
    while (true) {
        NodeHybrid node = stack.peek();
        if (node.parentA.children.size() > node.childrenB.size()) {
            stack.push(new NodeHybrid(node.parentA.children.get(node.childrenB.size())));
        } else {
            NodeTypeB converted = node.parentA.children.size() == 0
                ? convertLeaf(node.parentA)
                : convertParent(node.parentA, node.childrenB);
            stack.pop();
            if (stack.size() == 0) return converted;
            stack.peek().childrenB.add(converted);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# RLN traversal with backtracking
def itera(node):
    stack = node and [(node, [])]
    while stack:
        if stack[-1][0].children:
            stack.append((stack[-1][0].children.pop(), []))
            continue
        node = leaf(stack.pop()[0]) if stack[-1][0].children is None else parent(*stack.pop())
        if stack: stack[-1][1].append(node)
    return node


# test
from collections import namedtuple
Node = namedtuple("Node", "val children", defaults=[None])
leaf = lambda node: Node(node.val + 1000)
parent = lambda node, children: Node(node.val + 100, children)
recur = lambda node: node and (parent(node, list(map(recur, reversed(node.children)))) if node.children else leaf(node))
nodeA = Node(9, [Node(8, [Node(7, [Node(6), Node(5)])]), Node(4, [Node(3)]), Node(2, [Node(1), Node(0)])])
nodeB = Node(109, [Node(102, [Node(1000), Node(1001)]), Node(104, [Node(1003)]), Node(108, [Node(107, [Node(1005), Node(1006)])])])
assert recur(nodeA) == itera(nodeA) == nodeB


"""
nodeA
9
├── 8
│   └── 7
│       ├── 6
│       └── 5
├── 4
│   └── 3
└── 2
    ├── 1
    └── 0

nodeB
109
├── 102
│   ├── 1000
│   └── 1001
├── 104
│   └── 1003
└── 108
    └── 107
        ├── 1005
        └── 1006
"""
```